# how access nested objects in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, object

i'm trying to access `location.name` from nested object from api "free weather api", but always show error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')`. i write `location.name` at the 'p' tag at html structure

the object looks like this:

```
{
    "location": {
        "name": "London",
        "region": "City of London, Greater London",
        "country": "United Kingdom",
        "lat": 51.52,
        "lon": -0.11,
        "tz_id": "Europe/London",
        "localtime_epoch": 1678003398,
        "localtime": "2023-03-05 8:03"
    },
    "current": {
        "last_updated_epoch": 1678003200,
        "last_updated": "2023-03-05 08:00",
        "temp_c": 4.0,
        "temp_f": 39.2,
        "is_day": 1,
        "condition": {
            "text": "Overcast",
            "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/122.png",
            "code": 1009
        },
        "wind_mph": 4.3,
        "wind_kph": 6.8,
        "wind_degree": 300,
        "wind_dir": "WNW",
        "pressure_mb": 1022.0,
        "pressure_in": 30.18,
        "precip_mm": 0.0,
        "precip_in": 0.0,
        "humidity": 60,
        "cloud": 100,
        "feelslike_c": 2.3,
        "feelslike_f": 36.1,
        "vis_km": 10.0,
        "vis_miles": 6.0,
        "uv": 1.0,
        "gust_mph": 5.8,
        "gust_kph": 9.4
    }
}
```

and this is my code :

```
function App() {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);
  
  async function getData() {
    const key = "KEY";
    const area = "london";
    const response = await fetch(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${key}&q=${area}`);
    const result = await response.json();
    setWeather(result);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>{weather.location.name}</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

so how can i access `location.name` correctly ?

Comment: `weather` is initially an empty object with no `location` property, so initially `weather.location` will be `undefined`, giving you an error when you use `.name` on it. Use optional chaining `weather.location?.name` to check that `weather.location` isn't null/undefined before using `.name` on it, or use some other method to check if `weather.location` is defined before trying to access `.name`. You can also give your state an initial `location` property also which will avoid the issue with `weather.location` being unndefined initially.

Comment: oke thanks it work, i have another question what do you think about my code to call api using react js ? is it the good way or the bad way? or maybe there is another way?

Comment: It's ok, but it will have issues if your component unmounts before your API call is complete. See [`useFetch()`](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-fetch) for an example on how that can be handled